# Is there any way to configure Android Studio's linter to recognize new classes unsupported by the minimum SDK version?

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio's linter has several checks for calling new APIs unsupported by older versions of Android:

- Attribute unused on older versions
- Calling new methods on older versions
- Not overriding abstract methods on older platforms
- Using inlined constants on older versions

However, it appears to be missing a linter rule to detect the presence of a new class. As such, it is possible to do something like cast an object to a class declared in a newer version of the SDK (which will crash) without being caught by the linter.

Is there any way to enable this behaviour?